# ID masks for reflections

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to get ID masks or otherwise isolate an objects reflection in the compositor? For example, if I have a sphere above a reflective plane, I can set an ID mask on the sphere and use that to manipulate it in the compositor. But then the reflection will no longer be accurate. If I want to do the same manipulation on the reflection, I have no way to get it.

Comment: Do you mean that if object B is reflected on the surface of object A, that you can use an ID mask for object B to play with its reflection?

Comment: Yes. That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Glossy Pass** both in *Compositing* and *Shading*

### Compositing

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

### Shading

You can apply a *Light Path Node* to the Sphere Material:
[image]